# How to fix the npm ERR! code I get every time that I type npm start into the command line

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm attempting to create an application in React and am unable to as I'm receiving this error message after typing in "npm start" into the command line:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/a1234/Downloads/meditation-app-master/food recipe/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/a1234/Downloads/meditation-app-master/food recipe/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/a1234/.npm/_logs/2019-10-22T20_04_28_278Z-debug.log
```

Note: I have already attempted a few possible solutions that have been suggested on Stackoverflow, such as typing in "npm cache clean --force" and then reinstalling npm. This did not work. I'm also up to date on the latest version of npm (6.11.3).

Comment: does your package.json contain start scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename `food recipe` to `food-recipe`.
Spacing in your project name will mess with your package.json